# How to block access to a specific port on docker

Tags: docker, security, firewall, access-control

I have a docker container which exposes a RESTful API on a specific port (e.g. 4567) on a host machine. According to security requirements, I need to block all requests coming to this port (i.e. 4567) except the one coming from a specific application (say a scheduler like oozie). I'm not very familiar with firewalls, but I'm guessing the first part (blocking on access to the port) can be done in the firewall, but how can I open access to only one application?

Comment: If the other application is another docker container you don't even need to expose any ports, just make sure they use the same docker network..

Comment: no the other application is not in a docker container

Comment: There is no way via TCP/ip you can tell what application a connection has come from, this is not a Docker issue, that's just how TCP/ip works.  Other options is maybe setting your firewall to allow only certain IP's, eg. the machine oozie is on.  Even better seen as this is a RESTfull service you might consider using a Reverse Proxy, these will even allow you to add Basic Auth or TLS even if your docker container doesn't implement it.   A good Reverse Proxy I've been using recently is https://traefik.io/

Comment: Apply CORS in response header.